# How do I custom validate an input in contact form 7

Tags: regex, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 and I created a text input for the user to input a date. I have in the placeholder mm/dd/yyyy. Currently I am trying to validate this format in that input. I tried using the date tag but on safari it does not so this is why I am using the text tag.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_date_validation', 20, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_date_validation', 20, 2);

function custom_text_validation($result, $tag) {
$type = $tag->type; //object instead of array
$name = $tag->name; //object instead of array

if($name == 'last-name') {
    $value = $_POST[$date-signed];
    if(!preg_match("^((0|1)\d{1})/((0|1|2)\d{1})/((19|20)\d{2})", $value )){ //new regex statement
        $result->invalidate($tag, "Invalid Date");
    }
}
return $result;
```

}

I want when the user does not put in the input the correct form for contact form 7 to display invalid date.

Comment: Note that unless you implement a very complicated regex pattern that accounts for the different number of days in each month, you're still going to end up allowing impossible dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex (it is more precise since we are using anchors at the beginning and end) and some errors you have done in your regex are corrected

```
^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([1][9][9]\d|[2]\d{3})$
```

The date pattern: mm/dd/yyyy

Years in this example should be between 1990 < year < 2999 (You can edit it to fit it in what you want)

Comment: Why all the single numbers in square brackets? You can just type the numbers by themselves as literals.

Comment: how does this work with the contact form 7 though? Im sure the regex is correct, just need to know if the function is also corrected.